# Install Remmina Quantal (12.10) on Precise (12.04)

Tags: remmina

I'm on precise, and using Remmina that's got some annoying window placement bugs.
The version that's packed with Quantal seems to have those bugs fixed, but when i look at "About" it's the same versions.
-How do I get the Quantal version of Remmina installed in Precise?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download it with all dependencies and install from :

**32 bit version**

1. http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/remmina/remmina-common_1.0.0-1ubuntu8_all.deb
2. http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/remmina/remmina_1.0.0-1ubuntu8_i386.deb
3. http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/remmina/remmina-plugin-rdp_1.0.0-1ubuntu8_i386.deb
4. http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/remmina/remmina-plugin-vnc_1.0.0-1ubuntu8_i386.deb

**64 bit version:**

1. http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/remmina/remmina-common_1.0.0-1ubuntu8_all.deb
2. http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/remmina/remmina_1.0.0-1ubuntu8_amd64.deb
3. http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/remmina/remmina-plugin-rdp_1.0.0-1ubuntu8_amd64.deb
4. http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/remmina/remmina-plugin-vnc_1.0.0-1ubuntu8_amd64.deb